# how to properly perform query by date in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a cronjob to delete an event that has been passed by using http trigger. today is 7th September, so the event at 5 september ( `6fqmROcWD7K1pTFtXmJJ` )like the picture below shall be captured in the query snapshot. but the document length is zero

[image]

here is the code I use:

```
export const cronJobDeletingPastEvents = functions.https.onRequest(async (request,response) => {

        const dateNow = Date.now()
        const pastEventsSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("events").where('dateTimeFinish', '<', dateNow).get()
        console.log(pastEventsSnapshot.docs.length) // <---- the result is zero

// perform some actions ....

}
```

I don't know what went wrong in here, but I guess this is because `dateNow` is number, but the field `dateTimeFinish` in firestore is `Timestamp` object. but i dont know how to fix that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work:

```
const dateNow = new Date()

const pastEventsSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("events").where('dateTimeFinish', '<', dateNow).get()
...
```

The followings would also work:

```
const dateNow = new Date('2018-09-07T01:25:54.000Z')
const dateNow = new Date('2018-09-07')
```