# Firebase Node.js then is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that I am calling and am getting this error: Not sure what to do? I tried removing the return statement and returning Primise.all() and returning batch.commit() and all failed I also had to make eventsRef a var instead of a const, not sure why.

Error:

```
TypeError: eventsRef.where(...).then is not a function
    at exports.deleteOldEventLocations.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:235:6)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:689:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:673:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Function:

```
exports.deleteOldEventLocations = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  var eventsRef = db.collection('events');
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const endDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const batch = db.batch();
  const fieldValue = db.FieldValue;

  var query = eventsRef.where('startDate', '<', endDate)
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            let eventRef = eventsRef.doc(doc.id);
            batch.update(eventRef, { g: fieldValue.delete() });
            batch.update(eventRef, { l: fieldValue.delete() });
        });
        batch.commit();
        return;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `get()`. So:

```
var query = eventsRef.where('startDate', '<', endDate)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      ...
```

Also see the documentation on [getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

Comment: thanks! is there a way to do what I'm doing comparing the dates since my dates are stored as timestamps on firebase, or do I need to store them as seconds instead to compare, since I am getting an error for that query above now

Comment: @Michael Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221830/how-to-properly-perform-query-by-date-in-firestore, it may help.